# How to make a file available to a Project running on Tomcat for downloading

Tags: javascript, java, html, tomcat, download

I have a project which requires me to upload an excel file , manipulate it and then give the option to download the modified file.

I have successfully uploaded the file on my local machine but after manipulating and giving the option to download by `<a href="/home/aman/projetc/a.xls" download="a.jsp">Download</a>` the download says "No file found" . How can i make this file available to the project ?
`

Answer (score 0):

The path "/home/aman/..." (a unix user directory) is not accessible from the net (or at least I hope so). You can create a different directory to store your downloads, maybe "/var/downloads", give Tomcat rights to read it, and add an external context to your server.xml (between the "host" element):

```
<host ...>
  <Context docBase="/var/downloads" path="/downloads" />
</host>
```

Then you should be able to access:

http://yourdomain.org/downloads/a.xls

Comment: Thanks , as i am very new to this i just though that writing <a href="/home/aman/projetc/a.xls" download="a.jsp">Download</a> willl do the job but one needs to create a servlet as well that will download the file . I just assumed that the former statement would magically download it for me which it wouldn't . So that was the problem . Thanks for the help .